# Can't access cloudfront and fastly files, web sites not loading

Tags: dns, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Note: this problem is independent of wire/wireless, iPad (with Google DNS)/Linux/Windows

I can't access several sites including stackoverlow (cdn.sstatic.net), aws.amazon.com (d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net), heroku, github etc for 3 days from Turkey with ISP Superonline.

When I try to enter aws.amazon.com, browser downloads html and some images properly but can't download some of them, those hosted on d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net or subdomains like that.

Chrome says several images from this subdomain are pending. So the web page loading never finishes.

I can't access http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net, it keeps loading for a while (30 sec to minutes). But when I use proxy over Amsterdam, it loads immediately.

Without proxy, I can get its IP with ping:
64 bytes from server-54-240-162-83.fra6.r.cloudfront.net (54.240.162.83): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=58.2 ms

While writing these, the previous URL became available after several hours and now github.com can't be accessed due to css files on its CDN: https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/github2-f227c0e7c55002ba0645fc8d3761d00bce36e248.css

$ wget https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/github2-f227c0e7c55002ba0645fc8d3761d00bce36e248.css
--2013-11-19 21:39:32--  https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/github2-f227c0e7c55002ba0645fc8d3761d00bce36e248.css
Resolving github.global.ssl.fastly.net (github.global.ssl.fastly.net)... 185.31.17.184, 185.31.17.185
Connecting to github.global.ssl.fastly.net (github.global.ssl.fastly.net)|185.31.17.184|:443... connected.
...
...
waits but no response.

What could be the cause of this problem? My ISP did not help.

UPDATE: Changing my IP has solved the problem. Seems like someone using that IP before me got banned by Cloudfront.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the exact same problem, Changing the DNS solved the issue. For me Coursera wasn't opening, neither 9GAG.

Changed my default DNS server provided by my ISP to the one given by google i.e.

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

I hope this solves your issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a lot of problems with some ISPs and DNS resolution on CloudFront. See this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=263168

Have you tried to change your DNS?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the exactly same problem; same situation as you.
I think we really experience exactly the same. (but for me happen just today)

I first noticed problem on cloudfront then fastly then I can connect to cloudfront but fastly.

To answer your question I have a possible speculation about the root of the problem.
However, if this speculation is true the issue can't be solved on our end.

I think it's because of LSN (or NAT444, CGN) that installed in ISP network.
(ISP don't want customers to notice this change.)

To check if this speculation is plausible please check your modem/router
if the IP address received from ISP is in this block 100.64.0.0/10
then that should explain the phenomenon.

My ISP recently deploy LSN short before this problem arise.
I think IP address pool in LSN is too small (poorly deploy by ISP) so too many users share the same IP address.

this cause CDN networks to think they got DOS attack from particular IP address.
then CDN networks will temporary block (or null route) the LSN IP address.

some note: I'm sure this is not about the DNS because fastly deploy some trick called "round robin DNS" to use with "client retry" and I tried connect more than one IP address from fastly and also check that the values (All A records received) are correct.

To workaround the issue you can setup SOCKS proxy on a VPS and write PAC script to redirect some traffic thru the proxy.

Comment: Well, that could be the reason as well. Thinking that this is a DDOS attack. My speculation was that the former IP-user had been banned by Cloudfront. Changing IP solved the problem.